# fill NSArray from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm new to Objective-C, and I would like to know how I can fill my NSArray from a NSDictionary ?

My NSDictionary look like this :

```
user =     {
    items =         (
                    {
            nom = nom1;
            prenom = prenom1;
        },
                    {
            nom = nom2;
            prenom = prenom2;
        },
                    {
            nom = nom3;
            prenom = prenom3;
        }
    );
};
```

It is based on a Json, and I want my array to be like :

```
"prenom1.nom1", "prenom2.nom2", "prenom3.nom3"
```

I've tried something like this

```
array = [self.users objectForKey:@"user"]
```

but the result is the same as in my dictionary.

Comment: I would suggest you to go through objective-C basics. array have add Object and dictionaries have ObjectForKey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` -

```
NSArray *itemsArray=[user objectForKey:@"items"];

NSMutableArray *outputArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[itemsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [outputArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[obj objectForKey:@"prenom"],[obj objectForKey:@"nom"]]];
}];
```

`outputArray` will contain your names in the required format

Comment: It works well ! Thank you ! I have the result I need :)

Comment: The block answer is great, although @Fogmeister's answer is slightly faster. See http://darkdust.net/writings/objective-c/nsarray-enumeration-performance

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDictionary *users = // your dictionary

NSArray *items = users[@"items"];

NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *item in items) {
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", item[@"prenom"], item[@"nom"]];

    [names addObject:name];
}
```

Using the dictionary you supplied this will add all the names in the format you wanted to the `names` array.